# RecyclerView nested ViewHolder child views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have problems with RecyclerView when I try to loop adding more child views to the parent view. When I scroll, it appears blank for a second. Is from Data binding or the view rendering?

Here is my code:

```
public class TournamentFixtureAdapter extends LoadMoreRecyclerViewAdapter<FixtureGroup> {
    private OnFixtureClickListener onFixtureClickListener = null;

    public TournamentFixtureAdapter(List<FixtureGroup> data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    protected RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateContentItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int contentViewType) {
        return new TournamentFixtureHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_tournament_fixture, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindContentItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        super.onBindContentItemViewHolder(holder, position);
        FixtureGroup fixtureGroup = data.get(position);
        ((TournamentFixtureHolder) holder).onFixtureClickListener = onFixtureClickListener;
        ((TournamentFixtureHolder) holder).parentPos = position;
        ((TournamentFixtureHolder) holder).binding.setFixtureGroup(fixtureGroup);
        ((TournamentFixtureHolder) holder).addFixtures(fixtureGroup.getFixtures());
    }

    public void setOnFixtureClickListener(OnFixtureClickListener onFixtureClickListener) {
        this.onFixtureClickListener = onFixtureClickListener;
    }

    static class TournamentFixtureHolder extends FixtureHolder {
        ListItemTournamentFixtureBinding binding = null;

        public TournamentFixtureHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(itemView);
        }
    }
}

public class FixtureHolder extends BaseAdapter.BaseHolder {
    LinearLayout           layoutMain             = null;
    OnFixtureClickListener onFixtureClickListener = null;
    int parentPos;

    public FixtureHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        layoutMain = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
        setIsRecyclable(layoutMain.getChildCount() > 0);
    }

    public void addFixtures(final ArrayList<Fixture> fixtures) {

        for (final Fixture fixture : fixtures) {
            LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(itemView.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_fixture, null);

            Utils.getDefaultClubLogo((NetworkImageViewPlus) parent.findViewById(R.id.netview_home_img)).setImageUrl(fixture.getHome().getImg(), AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader());
            Utils.getDefaultClubLogo((NetworkImageViewPlus) parent.findViewById(R.id.netview_away_img)).setImageUrl(fixture.getAway().getImg(), AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader());
            ViewFixtureBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(parent);

            layoutMain.addView(parent);
            binding.setFixture(fixture);

            parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onFixtureClickListener.onFixtureClick(parentPos, findFixturePosById(fixtures, fixture.getId()));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private int findFixturePosById(ArrayList<Fixture> fixtures, int id) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fixtures.size(); i++) {
            if (fixtures.get(i).getId() == id) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you have extended  LoadMoreRecyclerViewAdapter to RecyclerView.Adapter , why you are not doing all this inside LoadMoreRecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: @L-X I use two views in that adapter. One for the last item to make circle indicator for loading more data and second for normal view. So there are two view holders in the adapter

Answer (score 0):

If the problem was more on the data side (adapter), then it would probably be showing up on the normal layout, not just during scrolling.  For instance, if you were loading images from a slow server, the initial display would be slow.  Since it's only happening when you scroll, that points more to a problem with the layout manager.

For every new view, you have to get it from the adapter, and add it to the layout.  If you allow maximum dx in horizontal/vertical scrolling, and have recycled views outside of the screen display cached, it's likely that things will appear blank prior the layout manager getting the new views from the adapter and laying them out.

So there are two factors - horizontal and/or vertical dx is too large, too soon, and the number of recycled (or scrapped) views is too small.  So the solution is to either slow down scrolling, or to increase the number of views you are adding off-screen.

Comment: I think increasing the number of views maybe works.. Could you provide the sample code of it.

Comment: If you're writing your own custom layout manager or extending another one - once the scroll methods are called (scrolledVerticallyBy, ScrollHorizontallyBy) - then you're in control - you know what the dx is, so whether or not they see blank depends on whether or not you lay out views before offsetting the user to the new location.  Just make sure the new views are laid out before offsetting the user to that area and there should be no grey space.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I managed to solve this. Maybe it's a little hack but it does solve the problems. I override the getContentItemViewType by return the size of child views that I have to generate at onCreateContentItemViewHolder. Again Thank you @Dennis Sheil